# Link to content on my PHP structure

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

My PHP code in Views 2:

```
<?php
$back_image_url = db_result(db_query("select files.filepath from {content_type_team} as ctb inner join {files} as files on files.fid = ctb.field_member_photo_fid  where ctb.nid = %d",$data->nid));
$presetname = 'team_member';
$preset = imagecache_preset_by_name($presetname);
$src = $back_image_url;
$dst = imagecache_create_path($presetname, $src);
// Ensure existing derivative or try to create it on the fly
if (file_exists($dst) || imagecache_build_derivative($preset['actions'], $src, $dst)) {
  $back_image_url_preset = "<img src='". variable_get('static_url', base_path()) . "". $dst."' alt='".$data->node_title."'/>";
}

$html_code = "<li class='team_members'>";
$html_code .= "<div class='ManagementTeam_FirstInfo'>
    <div class='Image'>
        ".$back_image_url_preset."
    </div>
    <div class='Name'>".$data->node_title."</div>
    <div class='Title'>".$data->node_data_field_member_photo_field_unvan_value."</div>
    <div class='DetailLink Absolute'>
        <a>".t("detayl? bilgi")."</a>
    </div>
</div></li>";

echo $html_code;

?>
```

I want link content o `li` Tried add before `a` tag but not working. Like this:

```
$html_code = "<a href='".$data->node."'><li class='team_members'>";
```

Not working. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$html_code = "<li class='team_members'><a href='".$data->node."'>content</a></li>";
```

Comment: Tried but not working. <li class="team_members"><a href=""></a><div class="ManagementTeam_FirstInfo"><a href="">

Comment: what you are putting inside li can u post whole li